# Filter src/main/resources for integration testing

Tags: java, maven, testing, ejb-3.1

I am trying to filter a properties file in src/main/resources for testing only with a mock.  Next revert back to filtering for the real class.

This is my setup:

src/main/resources/META-INF/ejb-jar.xml

in ejb-jar.xml

```
...

<ejb-link>${ejb.link.class}</ejb-link>
</ejb-local-ref>
```

src/main/resources/config.properties

in config.properties:
`ejb.link.class = Mock`

pom.xml

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <id>filter-resources</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>src/main/resources/config.properties</filter>
                        </filters>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

In this example, this works fine for normal build.  I would like to have a different filter for testing.  Perhaps pull from src/test/resources, and when testing is done, the normal cycle is ran with the needed filter for production.

I can't seem to figure out the right sequence for execution for testing.

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks,

Abe